# Why am not getting the right char values from scanf(c Linux vi) when scanning a file?

Tags: c, linux, file

This is the contents of my file

```
2
00000100+10000001
```

Basically what I want to do is read in the 2 as an int and the two following 0s as chars. 
My code for doing is (would copy and paste but don't know how from vi into notepad, tried (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173704/how-to-copy-and-paste-to-another-application-from-linux-shellvim)

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int times;
    scanf("%d",&times);
    printf("Number of times=%d ",times);
    char  num1;
     scanf("%c",&num1);
    char  num2;
    scanf("%c",&num2);
    int n = num1=='0'?0:1;
    int n2 = num2 == '0'?0:1;
printf("The next two digits are %d and %d\n",n,n2);
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiled fine and I was able to create the executable from gcc. 
And the output i got from running this program and redirecting standard input to the file is 
First file redirection command with executable

```
$ ./a.out < input.txt
```

And the result:

```
Number of times=2 The next two digits are 1 and 0
```

The two is printed correctly. I don't understand why the next digit is one though. From my understanding, won't `scanf` see that the next character is '0', or is there something else blocking it? It does eventually get to the right character I want it to get to, '0'. Does anyone know why the 1 is being outputted. From the way I coded it (I know it's bad design), any char not a '0' will set the corresponding int to 1. I just want to know what element is causing this one to happen and how to avoid this problem.

Comment: Drat my OCR *still* isn't working on a white-on-black code image =(

Comment: You say This is the contents of my file is 

`2` 
`00000100+10000001`.. But In your program NO file concept...

Comment: Is your "file" be fed via `./program < inputFileNameGoesHere` ? Just curious.

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR: the question shows I/O redirection being used on the command line.

Comment: yeah file redirection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not recognize it, but the newline **is** a character.
So `num1` gets to be `'\n'` and because your test (`num1 == '0'`) doesn't check for whitespace `n` becomes 1 ..

You can avoid this by prefixing a space to `%c` in scanf. This will force scanf to ignore whitespace

Comment: Or prefix it with `%*[\n]` to ignore newlines but not other whitespace. Being more specific is often better, and it allows you to read a blank, tab etc with `%c`.