# How to use a shortcut to read in the price amount without the dollar sign in C?

Tags: c

This question is similar to a question i asked before [Why am not getting the right char values from scanf(c Linux vi) when scanning a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175781/why-am-not-getting-the-right-char-values-from-scanfc-linux-vi-when-scanning-a) .

I learned from the answers to that question that you can use scanf like scanf(" %c") to skip over blank spaces and white lines when reading in a character. Is there a shortcut like this that you can work with money too? Say the user types $4.22 into standard in. Is there a scanf that lets you skip over special characters and then interpret that money amount as a float? Or do you just have to scanf the character first and then scanf the float money amount?

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? I thought this was a good clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for certain there will be a $, then you can include that in the format, like scanf("$%d.%d", &dollars, &cents). Try it!

```
$ cat scan.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int dollars, cents;
  scanf("$%d.%d", &dollars, &cents);
  printf("That's %d dollars and %d cents.\n", dollars, cents);
  return 0;
} 
$ make scan
cc     scan.c   -o scan
$ ./scan 
$4.22
That's 4 dollars and 22 cents.
$
```

Comment: So that's basically telling C that the input will be in the format of "$%d" and you want to take the part after $ and treat it as a decimal value

Comment: Yes, where decimal means base-10 integer, not a number that uses a decimal point to separate the whole and fractional parts.

Comment: To be clear, it's telling *scanf*, not C. The scanf/printf family of functions effectively use their own mini specification language, which, although part of the C spec, is quite distinct from the core language itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a shortcut like this that you can work with money too?

Unfortunately no, not as a part of the language itself.  But certainly such a library exists that you might use.  You just have to go to the trouble to compile/link against it and make sure you distribute it if it's dynamically linked.

> skip over special characters and then interpret that money amount as a float?

Note well!  Do not represent currency as a floating point numeral.  The behavior it uses to approximate real numbers is not appropriate for currency.  It will introduce inaccuracies.

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a popular reference (though perhaps a bit overwhelming).

Comment: is there a something like Big Decimal in java in C?

Comment: Do you have a shorter reference? I don't think i have the time to read that

Comment: [Superman III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_III) is another good reference about the dangers of doing floating point arithmetic on monetary values.

Comment: The first lesson to be learned from David Goldberg's good article is that if you can avoid using floating point arithmetic for accuracy-sensitive calculations, you probably should, because it's quite complicated. You can learn that just by seeing the size of the article, assuming you trust the person(s) who directed you to it.